# Need a way to update two gitlab repositories through single intellij project window

Tags: intellij-idea, gitlab

I am working on a project which is hosted on a particular gitlab repository. Often we dont get to connect to this repository because of network issues. Hence I have created my own local gitlab repository.

Now to keep the both repositories updated, i have to copy paste the code from one folder linked to one repository to other folder which is linked to other repository.

Is there a way in intellij wherein i can work in the same window but when committing and pushing the changes, both the repositories get updated at the same time ?

Regards,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I think it is far, far easier to use Git from the terminal/powershell.

If you are interested in using the terminal, or powershell, with Git, and want set multiple remote origins, then there is a already a [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations) about pushing and pulling from multiple remote locations.

---

Otherwise, look at Intellij's VCS menu, then select "Git."

[image]

Then select "remotes":

[image]

Then get add your other Git remotes by clicking "+" and add:

[image]

Add you should be set. Just select which remote you would like to push to.